# Problems building latest axis2 with maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-axis, building

I checked out latest version of axis2 from http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/axis/axis2/java/core/trunk/ and installed newest maven.

After execution of mvn install I got the following. Please help me, what am I doing wrong?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.axis2:axis2-transport-http:bundle:1.7.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar -> duplicate declaration of version (?) @ line 116, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Parent
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Resource bundle
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Kernel
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Data Binding
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - Local
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Addressing
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - Base
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - testkit
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - HTTP
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Code Generation
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - ADB Codegen
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Java2WSDL
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Repository Maven Plugin
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Fast Infoset
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Clustering
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Scripting
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - SAAJ
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Metadata
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JAXWS
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Test Utilities
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - XMLBeans Data Binding
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - WSDL2Code Maven Plugin
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JAXWS Integration Tests
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - MTOM Policy
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - spring
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - OSGi Integration
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Integration
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JiBX Data Binding
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JSON
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - MEX
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - MTOM Policy module
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Ping
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Version Service
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - SOAP Monitor Servlet
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - SOAP Monitor Module
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - AAR Maven Plugin
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Ant Plugin
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Eclipse Codegen Plugin
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Eclipse service Plugin
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Intellij IDEA Plugin
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Java2WSDL Maven Plugin
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - MAR Maven Plugin
[INFO] Apache Axis2 Simple HTTP server Maven Plugin
[INFO] Axis2 quickstart archetype
[INFO] Axis2 quickstart-web archetype
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JAXB-RI Data Binding
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - CORBA
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JAXWS (mar)
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Web Application module
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - JMS
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - Mail
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - TCP
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - UDP
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - XMPP
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Root
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Axis2 - Parent 1.7.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.1:enforce (default) @ axis2-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.1:process (default) @ axis2-parent ---
[INFO] Setting property: classpath.resource.loader.class => 'org.codehaus.plexus.velocity.ContextClassLoaderResourceLoader'.
[INFO] Setting property: velocimacro.messages.on => 'false'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.loader => 'classpath'.
[INFO] Setting property: resource.manager.logwhenfound => 'false'.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.2:install (default-install) @ axis2-parent ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Axis2\modules\parent\pom.xml to C:\Users\serge\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-parent\1.7.0-SNAPSHOT\axis2-parent-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Axis2 - Resource bundle 1.7.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.1:enforce (default) @ axis2-resource-bundle ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.1:bundle (default) @ axis2-resource-bundle ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.1:process (default) @ axis2-resource-bundle ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.2:resources (default-resources) @ axis2-resource-bundle ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) @ axis2-resource-bundle ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ axis2-resource-bundle ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Axis2\modules\resource-bundle\src\test\resources
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ axis2-resource-bundle ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.13:test (default-test) @ axis2-resource-bundle ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.2:jar (default-jar) @ axis2-resource-bundle ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Axis2\modules\resource-bundle\target\axis2-resource-bundle-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.2:install (default-install) @ axis2-resource-bundle ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Axis2\modules\resource-bundle\target\axis2-resource-bundle-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\serge\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-resource-bundle\1.7.0-SNAPSHOT\axis2-resource-bundle-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Axis2\modules\resource-bundle\pom.xml to C:\Users\serge\.m2\repository\org\apache\axis2\axis2-resource-bundle\1.7.0-SNAPSHOT\axis2-resource-bundle-1.7.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Apache Axis2 - Kernel 1.7.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.1:enforce (default) @ axis2-kernel ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-remote-resources-plugin:1.1:process (default) @ axis2-kernel ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.2:resources (default-resources) @ axis2-kernel ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.2:run (process-resources) @ axis2-kernel ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
     [copy] Copying 1 file to C:\Axis2\modules\kernel\target\classes\org\apache\axis2\i18n
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) @ axis2-kernel ---
[INFO] Compiling 349 source files to C:\Axis2\modules\kernel\target\classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\MIMEBuilder.java:[30,26] error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist

[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\MIMEBuilder.java:[31,26] error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist

[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\DataSourceBuilder.java:[63,62] error: package javax.mail.util does not exist

[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\MIMEBuilder.java:[42,8] error: cannot find symbol

[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\MIMEBuilder.java:[44,21] error: cannot find symbol

[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\MIMEBuilder.java:[45,17] error: cannot find symbol

[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\DataSourceBuilder.java:[60,22] error: no suitable method found for createOMElement(DataSourceBuilder.ByteArrayDataSourceEx,String,OMNamespace)

[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\DataSourceBuilder.java:[80,24] error: cannot find symbol

[INFO] 8 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Parent ............................. SUCCESS [0.437s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Resource bundle .................... SUCCESS [0.328s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Kernel ............................. FAILURE [2.948s]
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Data Binding ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - Local .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Addressing ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - Base ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - testkit ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - HTTP ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Code Generation .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - ADB Codegen ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Java2WSDL .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Repository Maven Plugin ..... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Fast Infoset ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Clustering ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Scripting .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - SAAJ ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Metadata ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JAXWS .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Test Utilities ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - XMLBeans Data Binding .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - WSDL2Code Maven Plugin ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JAXWS Integration Tests ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - MTOM Policy ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - spring ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - OSGi Integration ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Integration ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JiBX Data Binding .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JSON ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - MEX ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - MTOM Policy module ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Ping ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Version Service .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - SOAP Monitor Servlet ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - SOAP Monitor Module ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - AAR Maven Plugin ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Ant Plugin .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Eclipse Codegen Plugin ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Eclipse service Plugin ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Intellij IDEA Plugin ........ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - Java2WSDL Maven Plugin ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - tool - MAR Maven Plugin ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 Simple HTTP server Maven Plugin ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Axis2 quickstart archetype ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Axis2 quickstart-web archetype .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JAXB-RI Data Binding ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - CORBA .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - JAXWS (mar) ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Web Application module ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - JMS .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - Mail ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - TCP .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - UDP .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Transport - XMPP ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Axis2 - Root ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.852s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jul 31 07:25:36 CDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/362M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.1:compile (default-compile) on project axis2-kernel: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\MIMEBuilder.java:[30,26] error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\MIMEBuilder.java:[31,26] error: package javax.mail.internet does not exist
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\DataSourceBuilder.java:[63,62] error: package javax.mail.util does not exist
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\MIMEBuilder.java:[42,8] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\MIMEBuilder.java:[44,21] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\MIMEBuilder.java:[45,17] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\DataSourceBuilder.java:[60,22] error: no suitable method found for createOMElement(DataSourceBuilder.ByteArrayDataSourceEx,String,OMNamespace)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] \Axis2\modules\kernel\src\org\apache\axis2\builder\DataSourceBuilder.java:[80,24] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :axis2-kernel
```

and here is the portion of pom since the whole thing is to big to post

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  ~ Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
  ~ or more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file
  ~ distributed with this work for additional information
  ~ regarding copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file
  ~ to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
  ~ "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  ~ with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  ~ software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  ~ "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  ~ KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the
  ~ specific language governing permissions and limitations
  ~ under the License.
  -->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache</artifactId>
        <version>8</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Apache Axis2 - Root</name>
    <inceptionYear>2004</inceptionYear>
    <url>http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/</url>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>jira</system>
        <url>http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <modules>
        <module>modules/resource-bundle</module> <!-- Must be first in the list! -->
        <module>modules/adb</module>
        <module>modules/adb-codegen</module>
        <module>modules/addressing</module>
        <module>modules/codegen</module>
        <module>modules/fastinfoset</module>
        <module>modules/integration</module>
        <module>modules/java2wsdl</module>
        <module>modules/jibx</module>
        <module>modules/json</module>
        <module>modules/kernel</module>
        <module>modules/mex</module>
        <module>modules/mtompolicy</module>
        <module>modules/mtompolicy-mar</module>
        <module>modules/parent</module>
        <module>modules/ping</module>
        <module>modules/samples/version</module>
        <module>modules/soapmonitor/servlet</module>
        <module>modules/soapmonitor/module</module>
        <module>modules/spring</module>
        <module>modules/testutils</module>
        <module>modules/tool/axis2-aar-maven-plugin</module>
        <module>modules/tool/axis2-ant-plugin</module>
        <module>modules/tool/axis2-eclipse-codegen-plugin</module>
        <module>modules/tool/axis2-eclipse-service-plugin</module>
        <module>modules/tool/axis2-idea-plugin</module>
        <module>modules/tool/axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin</module>
        <module>modules/tool/axis2-mar-maven-plugin</module>
        <module>modules/tool/axis2-repo-maven-plugin</module>
        <module>modules/tool/axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</module>
        <module>modules/tool/simple-server-maven-plugin</module>
        <module>modules/tool/archetype/quickstart</module>
        <module>modules/tool/archetype/quickstart-webapp</module>
        <module>modules/webapp</module>
        <module>modules/xmlbeans</module>
        <module>modules/scripting</module>
        <module>modules/jaxbri</module>
        <module>modules/metadata</module>
        <module>modules/saaj</module>
        <module>modules/jaxws</module>
        <module>modules/jaxws-mar</module>
        <module>modules/jaxws-integration</module>
        <module>modules/clustering</module>
        <module>modules/corba</module>
        <module>modules/osgi</module>
        <module>modules/transport/local</module>
        <module>modules/transport/http</module>
        <module>modules/transport/base</module>
        <module>modules/transport/jms</module>
        <module>modules/transport/mail</module>
        <module>modules/transport/tcp</module>
        <module>modules/transport/testkit</module>
        <module>modules/transport/udp</module>
        <module>modules/transport/xmpp</module>
    </modules>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- This profile needs to be activated when doing the release:prepare
                 (by adding -Peverything) to make sure that the release plugin updates
                 the version numbers of all relevant submodules. It must contain
                 all modules not built by default, i.e. the set of modules used
                 by this profile must be the union of the module sets of all
                 other profiles. -->
            <id>everything</id>
            <modules>
                <module>modules/distribution</module>
                <module>modules/samples/java_first_jaxws</module>
                <module>modules/samples/jaxws-addressbook</module>
                <module>modules/samples/jaxws-calculator</module>
                <module>modules/samples/jaxws-interop</module>
                <module>modules/samples/jaxws-samples</module>
                <module>modules/samples/jaxws-version</module>
            </modules>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>apache-release</id>
            <modules>
                <module>modules/distribution</module>
            </modules>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-beta-1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>enforce</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <rules>
                                        <!-- We need Maven 2.1 because the prepare-package phase
                                             doesn't exist in Maven 2.0 -->
                                        <requireMavenVersion>
                                            <version>2.1.0</version>
                                        </requireMavenVersion>
                                    </rules>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>generate-timestamp</id>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>execute</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <source>
                                        import java.util.Date 
                                        import java.text.MessageFormat 
                                        project.properties['buildTimestamp'] = MessageFormat.format("{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}", new Date())
                                    </source>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                        <!-- Configure an additional execution. The configuration
                             is the same as the one specified together with the execution
                             in the pre-site phase.  -->
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>distribution-javadoc</id>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>aggregate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>site</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <!-- Override the execution defined in org.apache:apache
                                     so that the source-release assembly is not built.
                                     We define our own source distribution in modules/distribution. -->
                                <id>source-release-assembly</id>
                                <configuration>
                                    <phase>package</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>single</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <skipAssembly>true</skipAssembly>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>package-other-distributions</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src/main/assembly/doc.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>prepare-dists</id>
                                <!-- Must be done in the install phase after the checksum and signature for
                                     the docs distribution has been generated. -->
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the javax.mail.internet and javax.mail.util libraries. It clearly says so in the output you posted. You need to add them to your project.

There could be many more problems, but without even posting your pom there really isn't any way for us to know.

Also, a simple google search would have provided the answer.

Comment: I tried exactly what you are suggesting bu had no clue where to put those libraries. I tried to put them into sdk/lib folder and sdk/jre with no difference in building results. I will also post my pom here

Comment: You add the to your <dependencies> section in your pom.xml. You can search for maven libraries at http://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: would I add something like this?
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
            <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
 what would i put in groupId ?

Comment: There are many, many tutorials and resources for learning the basics of Maven. Dependencies are one of the most basic aspects of Maven. I suggest learning the basics first, then start asking for help. You can start with [Maven in 5 min] (http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). Also, I'm fairly sure Axis2 is available in the Maven repo's, is there a specific reason you are compiling from source?

Comment: I understand your point, the problem is I did not create the project and I'm following instructions on their web page. I'm trying to understand if I missed something in the instruction or there is something they did not say and expect for me to know. Here is the link https://builds.apache.org/job/Axis2/site/svn.html

Comment: Ok but why do you even need to compile the axis2 source? It is available via maven. You are missing something, you are missing those libraries or they aren't in your classpath. Axis2 libraries are available in Maven so if you don't know what you are doing with the source then there really isn't any reason to use it over precompiled, readily available jars.

Comment: I got your point and thank you. I think I will look into maven axis2 libs.

Comment: I've downloaded the latest axis2 snapshot from http://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/axis2/axis2/SNAPSHOT/ however I cannot find the dependency list of jars I need at runtime...

Comment: start a new question, this thread is months old and has nothing to do with you

Answer (score 1):

It is not good practice to build source from trunk as it is under development ... Go and download a RELEASE from http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/download.cgi
and prepare your environment as specified http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/installationguide.html#env-src

Comment: I can not download the release because I need version 1.7.0 SNAPSHOT and not 1.6.2 (1.7 fixes some issues with wsdl generation)